How to autofit text in merged cells?
I'm trying to write VBA code that will Autofit the text in merged cells.
ex.  Cells C2:D2 are merged.  Text is assigned to these cells.
What function or process is supposed to be used for this situation?  Have searched and unable to find anything that works.
Have tried using Autofit for the column(s), but doesn't work.
Have tried all standard autofit techniques and nothing works. e.g. Double clicking the column line, etc.

I don't believe AutoFit works with merged cells. Might be better to use Center Across Selection instead of merging.

MSFT Says it's not supported.  So you can't specifically use autofit to do this. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-cannot-use-the-autofit-feature-for-rows-or-columns-that-contain-merged-cells-in-excel-34b54dd7-9bfc-6c8f-5ee3-2715d7db4353

It's messy, but does the accepted answer here: vb macro string width in pixel help? You'd have to do it for all cells in the columns, though, and track the widest, bearing merged cells in mind.

What code? Showing what you are trying would be a start.
